# MI_RESULT_FAILED on Copy-Item in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am running PowerShell on CentOS 7.x.  I converted working individual commands when running within PowerShell via pwsh to a PowerShell script and then it no longer works.  Can someone please shed me some light on what I did wrong?

Here's the working individual commands when running within PowerShell via pwsh.

```
PS /home/user1/Downloads> $userPw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "user1password" -AsPlainText -Force
PS /home/user1/Downloads> cd
PS /home/user1> $userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "user1win", $userPw
PS /home/user1> $s = New-PSSession -computerName 192.168.20.143 -credential $userCredential -Authentication Negotiate
PS /home/user1> Copy-Item -Path /home/user1/Downloads/gssntlmssp-0.7.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm -Destination "C:\users\user1win\Desktop" -ToSession $s
PS /home/user1> exit
```

Here's the script when I converted to a PowerShell script so I can pass arguments into it.  remote-copy.ps

```
    $remoteHost = $args[0]
    $username = $args[1]
    $pwp = $args[2]
    $source = $args[3]
    $destination = $args[4]
    
    Write-Host "Remote Host: '$remoteHost'"
    Write-Host "Username: '$username'"
    Write-Host "Password: '$pwp'"
    Write-Host "Source: '$source'"
    Write-Host "Destination: '$destination'"
    
    $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwp -AsPlainText -Force
    
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $pw
    
    $s = New-PSSession -computerName $remoteHost -credential $cred -Authentication Negotiate
    
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -ToSession $s
```

When I run the script, I got the following error.

```
    [user1@rhel7-tm PowerShell]$ pwsh -File ./remote_copy.ps 192.168.20.143 user1win user1password /home/user1/Downloads/vte-0.28.2-10.el7.x86_64.rpm "C:\\users\user1win\Desktop"
    Remote Host: '192.168.20.143'
    Username: 'user1'
    Password: 'user1password'
    Source: '/home/user1/Downloads/vte-0.28.2-10.el7.x86_64.rpm'
    Destination: 'C:\users\user1win\Desktop'
    Copy-Item:                                                                                
Line |                                                                                        
19 |
Copy-Item -Path "$source" -Destination "$destination" -ToSession $s                      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                       |
Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message : MI_RESULT_FAILED For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
Copy-Item:                                                                                   Line |                                                                                        
19 |
Copy-Item -Path "$source" -Destination "$destination" -ToSession $s                       |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                       |
Failed to copy file /home/user1/Downloads/vte-0.28.2-10.el7.x86_64.rpm to remote target destination.
```

I would be greatly appreciate if someone can point me to where I did wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a false alarm.  The script does work.  The issue is by default the MaxEnvelopeSizekb in winrm/config is only 500kb.  I need to set to a bigger value if I want to send a bigger file.  To set MaxEnvelopSizekb to 500mb, you need to open PowerShell on Windows as Administrator and run the following command.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-WSManInstance -ResourceUri winrm/config -ValueSet @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb = "500000"}
```